# Power BI DAX Measure: Counting the distinct number of users by nested way of filtering

Tags: powerbi, dax, data-analysis, measure

I tried multiple ways to do this, but just can't find the final solution.
Precodition: it has to be a MEASURE, NOT calculated column

So my table looks like this:

| Name | Skill | Level |
| --- | --- | --- |
| John | SQL | 2 |
| John | SQL | 2 |
| Amy | Python | 1 |
| Amy | Python | 3 |
| Lena | CSharp | 2 |
| Lena | SQL | 2 |

The solution should be: count of people who have same level for the same skill. So in this example, the answer is 1 because only John has same skill and the same level.

It should be something like this:

**count number of people if, for the same skill, they have the same level number**

I don't know how to even search for the same skill in the same column.

EARLIER is not working for measure, and MAX is giving totally wrong answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
Same Skill Same Level = 
  COUNTROWS(
    FILTER(
      GROUPBY(
        'Table',
        'Table'[Name],
        'Table'[Skill],
        'Table'[Level],
        "Count", COUNTX(CURRENTGROUP(), 1)
      ),
      [Count] > 1
    )
  )
```

This will give you number of people and number of same skill & level. So if John had another skill with the same level, then it would show 2.

If you want distinct count of folks with one or more pairs then use:

```
Same Skill Same Level - people = 
  CALCULATE(
    DISTINCTCOUNT('Table'[Name]),
    FILTER(
      GROUPBY(
        'Table',
        'Table'[Name],
        'Table'[Skill],
        'Table'[Level],
        "Count", COUNTX(CURRENTGROUP(), 1)
      ),
      [Count] > 1
    )
  )
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast feedback. Looks like your solution is correct! Thanks again. :)

Comment: I only have one problem; when I try to write out those people; their name, skill or level, I get an error: it says that I can not print them because of summarizecolumns. Do you maybe know how to solve that problem; so that the solution is John SQL 2 Mary Python 3 etc., not only a number of people?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, can you share a mock-up of what you are after? You could use a Table Visual, add Name, Skill and Level, then add the first measure `Same Skill Same Level` as a visual filter `is not blank`.

Comment: I tried Table Visual, and then added Name, Skill or Level, however I got an error: "Can't display the visual" and the reason was: "Summarized Columns can not be used in this context". And I tried it with second measure - the second one was what I was looking for. The mockup should be in the upper example: John SQL 2 (so I should get the result, but not as a number. The result would have to say which people have pairs and what are those pairs.

Comment: I've updated both measures above to use `GROUPBY` instead of `SUMMARIZECOLUMNS`. Should work now in a Table/Matrix visual. Example: https://i.stack.imgur.com/p1ru6.png (I added John Python twice as a test)

Comment: You really know Power BI, thanks! Or maybe I know too little, but in my defense, I've been using DAX for a couple of days only. :) Ps. After using your second measure, I applied a filter on the measure (show only 1) and removed the measure from the visual so it resulted in exactly what I wanted. Thanks again :)